# Installing google analytics without pods, getting error ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-analytics

I'm currently not using pods at all for my project, instead i'm using carthage but unfortunately they don't have carthage support so I followed this tutorial here http://www.danishin.com/article/Google_Analytics_For_iOS_Without_Cocoapods but after I tried building the project i got `ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices` from `Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error .. Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` I've already looked around other questions/answers on here but didn't have any luck at all.

I've tried these things below

- Disabled bitcode
- Made sure library search paths had the correct path to libGoogleAnalyticsServices
- Deleted DerivedData, Cleaned, Closed XCode, Rebuild

Comment: You could use https://github.com/ksmandersen/GoogleReporter instead which is open-source and has CocoaPods/Carthage compatibility.

Comment: I know that adding google analytics to your project also automatically sends other data too by just having it imported into your project. Do you know if Google Reporter does this too?

Comment: No, it's for reporting events mostly.